# How to avoid div scaling when scaling text inside in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Looking around I found various topics regarding scaling text inside a div to fit its container and so on, but I'm interested on the inverse of that, hoow to avoid a div from scaling when a text inside is scaled without using hardcoded max-width and max-height properties. Take a look at the example bellow (also [code pen](https://codepen.io/danielx-art/pen/mdKEKLg)):

HTML:

```
<div class="text-container">
  <div class="text">Gallery</div>
  <div class="text">Contact</div>
  <div class="text">FAQ</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.text {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 200ms;
  border: 1px solid coral;
}

.text:hover {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

As you can see when hovering over a text it resizes and it moves the other texts around it, what I want is for the each text to resize on hover but the other ones to keep where they are, without hardcoding a max-width property. is it possible?

Comment: I wouldn't use flexbox in your case, display them as blocks and set an absolute left and top to each one of the elements. It will avoid the other ones moving around

Answer (score 0):

I thought there's no way to do that but after tests I found out you can do it with the `transform` property [scale()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale)

So, you need to create an element inside div

```
<div class="text">
  <span>Gallery</span>
</div>
```

Then you need to scale span element instead of div while hovering

```
span {
  transition: all 200ms; // for smoothness
  display: inline-block; // transform doesn't work on inline elements
}

.text:hover span {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

Finally, the code will look like

HTML:

```
<div class="text-container">
  <div class="text">
    <span>Gallery</span>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <span>Contact</span>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <span>FAQ</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.text {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 200ms;
  border: 1px solid coral;
}

span {
  transition: all 200ms;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text:hover span {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```